# How to set a widget to drag an undecorated Window in Vala?

Tags: user-interface, gtk, vala

This might seem like a simple question. I'm a beginner in Gtk and Vala Programming. I'm a beginner Programmer as well. I started off with Vala  Gtk GUI and now I have an undecorated Window that is not draggable.
I need to set a custom titlebar-like widget to drag the window. I have read that it is doable and seen it in action using Python, but not Vala.

[image]

I want to make the area between Add and Close draggable - it is a Gtk Horizontal box.

I need help in implementing this in Vala. Please Help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in method in Gtk+ to do this, since this is a task for the window manager. Why would you want to have no window decorations in the first place?

Comment: If you really want to do this and only support X11 (not Wayland, Windows, etc.) you could [call the X11 API](https://github.com/patrickhaller/no-wm/blob/master/x-move-resize.c) from your application.

Comment: It is just for the aesthetic beauty that the program will have with the titlebar removed. It is basically only a stickynotes widget, it won't really need a titlebar.So I thought, it looks better without decorations, so be it

Comment: Yes, but it _works_ better _with_ decorations.

Comment: The layout of your Add and Close buttons makes it sound like you want to use a GtkHeaderBar instead of a fully undecorated window. `Gtk.Window.set_titlebar()` will change the titlebar of a window to an arbitrary widget, such as a header bar. Other than that, you'd need to capture mouse events on the window itself and reposition the window each time.

Comment: @oldtechaa True that, but I don't want the Window Manager to mess up my beautiful minimal UI

Comment: @andlabs Is it possible to use a GtkHeaderBar for such a small widget.Doesn't it have a specific size setting? Can you tell me how to exactly do it in Vala?

Comment: After a bit more code, this is what it looks like 

http://i.imgur.com/7P4W2wK.png?1

Its starting to take shape with my little coding skills 

@JensMühlenhoff Will it work on all Linux Distros that way, except for the ones using Wayland?

Comment: @andlabs Thank you so much for the idea of using Headerbars. I just used it now it allows me to drag the window!!

http://i.imgur.com/C6ppsHL.png?1

Comment: You get a point for taking what I said and taking the next logical step of custom styling :)

Comment: Looks good. I thought of something like the GNOME apps, but since I haven't really used GTK3, I'm not one to give advice on it. Glad to see @andlabs posted a full answer this time so you could accept it. :)

Comment: Looks like your Vala and GTK skills aren't bad either to be able to quickly go and create a sample of things people suggest, even with little detail.

Comment: @oldtechaa yes, since my idea worked I turned it into an answer with more details =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTK+ does support *client-side decorations*, which means that you provide the window decoration instead of the window manager. This is done with `gtk_window_set_titlebar()`, which takes an arbitrary GtkWidget to use as the titlebar.

GTK+ provides GtkHeaderBar, a complete titlebar that you can add arbitrary widgets to (in the same way as GtkBox). You may have seen many GNOME programs use them already. Your screenshot looks like a job for GtkHeaderBar, with the Add button packed to the start and the Close button packed to the end. Just set that as the GtkWindow's titlebar and you should be good to go. (You may also need to remove the standard minimize/maximize/close buttons; there's a GtkHeaderBar method for that too.)

Of course, GtkHeaderBar by default looks like standard window manager decorations. You can use CSS to change the appearance, even to the point of changing the appearance of the buttons inside the headerbar (only). Your screenshots in your comments show you have already done that; great job!